# Python file running through Azure Batch stuck on "In progress"

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

Newbie with Azure Batch here.

I have created a pipeline in ADF to run a python script to call an API and do some data manipulations. I call this script by using a "Custom" activity through Azure Batch.

Tested this locally and the Python script itself runs and finishes perfectly. Through Azure, I can see that the script has run due to the CPU usage in the database. However, the script never finishes and goes to the next step:

[image]

The script code:

[image: Code of the python script. Exposed data has made black.]

The script is doing a cURL POST request to an interface which runs some SQL on the background. This should take roughly 15 minutes and finishes correctly if running locally.

If I'm looking at my pool in Azure Batch, I can see that I have 1 node in a running state at 100%.

[image]

After 12 hours, I'm getting this message from ADF:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot what is going on? Why is my script not finishing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @thedemons, added some information in the original post, I hope it's useful.